# How to create,open and set up connection with new database in oracle using SAP?

Tags: oracle10g, sapi, netweaver

Please let me know

How to create,open and set up connection with new database in oracle using SAP?

Application:SAP NW 6 and above
Oracle: 10g 
OS: Linux / Window

Answer (score 0):

SAP don't allow for full interact with underlying DBMS, you should use "Open SQL" for data store and retrieving. There are set of restricted possibilities of using native sql  in SAP application. For details, try to search for key "Native SQL" in built in help. But be careful with it, SAP system can use multiple types of DBMS and it's most likely that native sql instructions for one DBMS type would not work for another.